# Android: on screen rotation what should Fragment's onCreate() and onCreateView() do

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, screen-rotation

In my activity I have a check for savedInstanceState, making sure I am not creating multiple fragments

But my question is should I have similar checks in Fragment's onCreate() and onCreateView()

Because when I rotate screen Fragment's onCreate() and onCreateView() are called everytime.

Question is, Is it OK for these 2 methods to re-do there job after everyscreen rotation or they should have a savedInstanceState check as well.

Right now my onCreate() makes a service call and onCreateView inflates a view (Recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

When an activity or Fragment is recreated, the onCreate() method is first fired, followed by the onRestoreInstanceState() method, which enables you to retrieve the state that you savedpreviously in the onSaveInstanceState() method through the Bundle object in its argument:

```
@ Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
//---retrieve the information persisted earlier---
String ID = savedInstanceState.getString(“ID”);
}
```